# Python script calling `arp` produces error when run from crontab

Tags: python, subprocess, arp

**My server**:

```
Linux dhcpns 3.19.0-28-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 31 15:52:51 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**My Python script**:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import syslog, traceback
import subprocess as sp

def getarp():
  cmd = ["arp", "-a"]
  arp = sp.Popen(cmd, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
  output, err = arp.communicate()
  entries = output.splitlines()
  return entries

def syslog_trace(trace):
  log_lines = trace.split('\n')
  for line in log_lines:
    if len(line):
      syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_ALERT,line)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  try:
    lstArp =  getarp()
    print lstArp
  except Exception as e:
    syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_ALERT,e.__doc__)
    syslog_trace(traceback.format_exc())
    raise
```

When I run the script from the commandline it produces the expected output.
However, when I call the script from `crontab -e` (redirecting output to a file, obviously) the script fails.

**The log**:

```
Sep 28 18:36:01 dhcpns testarp.py[9984]: OS system call failed.
Sep 28 18:36:01 dhcpns testarp.py[9984]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Sep 28 18:36:01 dhcpns testarp.py[9984]: File "/home/ubuntu/testarp.py", line 23, in <module>
Sep 28 18:36:01 dhcpns testarp.py[9984]: lstArp =  getarp()
Sep 28 18:36:01 dhcpns testarp.py[9984]: File "/home/ubuntu/testarp.py", line 10, in getarp
Sep 28 18:36:01 dhcpns testarp.py[9984]: arp = sp.Popen(cmd, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
Sep 28 18:36:01 dhcpns testarp.py[9984]: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
Sep 28 18:36:01 dhcpns testarp.py[9984]: errread, errwrite)
Sep 28 18:36:01 dhcpns testarp.py[9984]: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
Sep 28 18:36:01 dhcpns testarp.py[9984]: raise child_exception
Sep 28 18:36:01 dhcpns testarp.py[9984]: OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

WTF?
What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commands that are run via cron inherit a different environment. In particular, `PATH` envvar may be different. To workaround it, specify the full path to `arp` program in your Python script or configure `PATH` in the corresponding crontab explicitly:

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/path/where/arp/lives
```

Comment: Ofcourse! I feel such a n00b! :-)  Guess it's been a long day. Thanks!